# Get Location without using LocationManager class in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used Google Map v2 to show user current location on the map with marker using its Latitude & Longitude .

I want to know is there any alternative to get the user's Current Location without using

```
LocationManager class
```

Any Help Appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do this by setting location change listener on googlmap

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                // get the current location here 

            }
        });
```

OR Try this

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.getMyLocation();
```

UPDATE

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationSource {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }



    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener arg0) {
        googleMap.getMyLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {

    }

}
```

Comment: it is also deprecated...http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary.html

Comment: I have priviously tried it ...googleMap.getMyLocation(); it gives nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can ask the user to provide its current location.

Comment: @Baschi...Any other possible solution

Comment: Not realy. I do not get why you need to avoid the `LocationManager` service. Its the default way to determine the location. Another way would be to retrieve the actual IP address of the device and use the IP range to determine a vague location.

Comment: :) I have done with it using the LocationClient and it is working ...Although there are not much writting on this technique ...but really thks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

This is where I have found Reference to do it .Below are the Links .I have LocationClient for this...

1. [Example for LocationClient](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/gfx/AndroidLocationClientExample/blob/master/src/com/example/locationexample/MainActivity.java&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE5Mc8z4qFaeGvkLZd8G0NF2J2HIQ)
2. [Reference for LocationClient](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html)

Hope this could b useful for AnyOne...Thks